# PeerJS - peer getting immediately disconnected

Tags: javascript, p2p, peerjs

Here is my very simple code:

```
let peer = new Peer('foo', {key: 'my-actual-key'});
console.log(.peer.disconnected);
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(.peer.disconnected)
}, 1000);
```

It prints:

```
false
true
```

Is this working right? How am I supposed to connect one peer to another if they are disconnected from the server immediately?

I'm using PeerJS's peer server.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was embedding the peer.js library from their CDN. As soon as I hosted the JS myself the connection was stable.

EDIT: Actually not. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the 'disconnected' event on the peer and check when is it called.

It is usually called when you navigate between pages.